# Toggle 3 classes onclick (Only toggling 2)

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, if-statement

My toggle function is only toggling through 2 of the 3 classes and not the third. It skips my star class and just toggles between my fact and barr classes. I've changed things around a bunch of ways and it's only toggling through 2 of 3 classes.

My Html

```
<div id="labalt"><a href="#">Alt</a></div>
  <h1 id="build_title" class="barr" >Barracks</h1>
```

My code

```
$("#labalt").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fact star barr");

if($(this).hasClass("fact"))
    {
    $("#build_title").html("Factory");
    }
else if($(this).hasClass("star"))
{
    $("#build_title").html("Starport");
    }
else
{
    $("#build_title").html("Barracks");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ra3Qv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get the code to cycle through all three texts on three consecutive clicks? Because that's not what `toggleClass` does. `toggleClass` toggles one or more classes on or off.

[As you can tell by this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e4hG/), clicking the link toggles both the border, the font size, and the italics class.

It starts off with none of the classes. On click 1, it will have all three classes. It will then match the first condition (it has the `fact` class), and since they are `else if`'s, no other conditions will be checked. The text will simply be set to "Factory".

On a second click, all three classes will be removed. It will not meet the first criteria (`fact`) or the second (`star`), so it will set the text to "Barracks".

On a third click, all three classes will be added again.

If you want it to cycle through the classes, you'd have to implement that manually; I do not know that there is any out of the box solution for that. You would either need to keep a cursor of some kind, or continuously iterate an array to check whichever class is currently active, and then move on to the next. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3nzE/); I'm sure it could be neater.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get it to cycle through all 3 titles as the button is clicked and my barr class is the default title and class. I'm new to jquery so I don't know of another way and I've googled the hell out of this problem.

Comment: @RyanDay: well, see my answer for a solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it works now. I'm still reading through the function, trying to fully understand what each line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's an attempt... shouldn't you be doing

```
$("#labalt").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("fact star barr");

if($(this).hasClass("fact"))
{
    $("#build_title").html("Factory");
}
if($(this).hasClass("star"))
{
    $("#build_title").html("Starport");
}
if($(this).hasClass("barr"))
{
    $("#build_title").html("Barracks");
}
});
```

Comment: This code makes it skip fact class and only do star and barr. ><

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/LRuZp/1/

I guess, there is a problem with your conditional statements.

```
Case 1.  <div id="labalt" class="fact"></div>

  Result after toggling: <div id="labalt" class="star barr">

Case 2.  <div id="labalt" class="fact star"></div>

  Result after toggling: <div id="labalt" class="barr">

Case 3. <div id="labalt" class=""></div>

  Result after toggling: <div id="labalt" class="fact star barr">
```

Using Your Conditional statements:

```
if($(this).hasClass("fact"))
{
$("#build_title").html("Factory");
}
else if($(this).hasClass("star"))
{
 $("#build_title").html("Starport");
}
else
{
  $("#build_title").html("Barracks");
}
```

At a time there can be two classes.

**Case 1:**
  The second if condition is set to true and the last condition remain unchecked. So, the last condition is never executed if "star" class is present, which is logically wrong if both "star barr" classes are present.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still running into the same problem.

Comment: Toggle classes function is working fine. Can you please give the initial html markup and the final html markup required after toggling classess.

Comment: I edited my original post with the html elements I'm trying to edit with the function.